# unable to import javax.media.*; (package does not exist) Why does it say so?

Tags: java, mp3, javasound

I have downloaded [JMF MP3 PLUGIN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html)  to play mp3 files. After downloading i place `mp3plugin.jar` into the project library of netbeans.

Then i start the code with the line :
 `import javax.media.*;`

But there is an error corresponding to this statement which says package `javax.media` does not exist. Why do i get this error ? I have tried searching about it but haven't found the solution. Please help me in this.
I have also placed `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\mp3plugin.jar` in the classpath variable.

Comment: Did you actually add it to the build path? I know you need to in eclipse, and I imagine netbeans would be the same way.

Comment: @ Collecter I have just included the jar file in my project library .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to import a Service Provider Interface at compile time.  Simply add it to the run-time class-path and it will be able to play mp3's as well as its (default) wave/pcm/midi files.

I use the [`mp3plugin.jar`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5B9wDXIGw9lRmpSbEUtenljd1k/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-miuzcGB8fsXn2EQh3sVolA) this way for DukeBox, a little player for M3U style playlists, and it works just fine.  Note that it will add the ability to read MP3 format using JavaSound (`javax.sound.sampled`).  If you intend playing the MP3 using the JMF player (which is unnecessary, and I do not recommend), you'll need to add the main JMF jar at both compile & run-time.

---

Here is an example [code for playing sounds](http://www.jsresources.org/examples/SimpleAudioPlayer.java.html) using JavaSound.  Don't be put off by the length of the code, most of that is comments and explanation.

It will compile without importing *any* of JMF.  If the `mp3plugin.jar` is on the *run-time* class-path, it should be capable of playing MP3s.

Comment: `..you'll need to add the main JMF jar at both compile & run-time` I am using windows. Why shouldn't i play mp3 using `JMF MP3 plugin` ?

Comment: why it is that after adding `mp3plugin.jar` in my project library of netbeans i get the error that package does not exist ? I tried adding `jl 1.0.1.jar` of JLayer in my library and it worked fine.

Comment: *"I am using windows."*  What OS are your potential *users* using? *"Why shouldn't i play mp3 using JMF MP3 plugin?"*  I never said that.  All I advised against was using the JMF based [MediaPlayer](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/bean/playerbean/MediaPlayer.html) for playing MP3s.  Read what I wrote again, carefully.

Comment: *"why it is that after adding mp3plugin.jar in my project library of netbeans i get the error that package does not exist ?"* Try this experiment, get the Jar in question (copy it) then rename the copy to '.zip'.  Double click to open in your favorite Zip program.  Do you see a `javax` sub-directory? *"I tried adding jl 1.0.1.jar of JLayer in my library and it worked fine."*  I don't use or provide help for the JLayer API.

Comment: *"NO ! It is not there."*  OK - that is some progress.  The point I am trying to make is that using the `mp3plugin.jar` has nothing directly to do with the classes in the `javax.media` package.  Instead, look to the `javax.sound.sampled` package for classes to load/play the MP3.  The latter `sampled` package is part of the J2SE (and has been since Java 1.3).  Have a read through the [info. page on the JavaSound tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for more details.

Comment: `javax.sound.sampled` does not support decoding and hence playing mp3

Comment: <head-desk/>  Which part of *"Note that it (`mp3plugin.jar`) will add the ability to read MP3 format **using JavaSound** (`javax.sound.sampled`)."* are you having trouble understanding?  Did you *read* the page I linked?  I am beginning to wonder if there is any possibility of *me* helping *you* in a way that *you* understand!

Comment: `The Java Sound API does not support many formats of sampled sound internally. In a 1.6.0_24 Oracle JRE getAudioFileTypes() will generally return {WAVE, AU, AIFF}. An MP3 decoder at least, is close by. The mp3plugin.jar of the Java Media Framework supports decoding MP3s.` That's what it talks about MP3 . I know this. My problem was to remove the error from the statement `import javax.media.*;` and i have not got the answer to this. We know that `javax` directory does not exist in the jar file that i have at the moment.What is the alternative. **I want the stmt `import javax.media.*;` to work**

Comment: What **class** in `javax.media` do you intend using?  And not to put too fine a point on it, but the only question you asked in the body of your question is *"Why do i get this error ? "*, which I feel has already been answered when you realized that the plugin.jar does not contain the `javax` packages.

Comment: `MediaLocator` and the `player` interface

Comment: It is the `Player` interface (capital 'P') but that won't do much good on its own.  The only class that *implements* that interface is `MediaPlayer` (linked in earlier comments).  If you want to go that way, it will be necessary to add the JMF core Jars to the compilation.  But as I said earlier, the JMF `MediaPlayer` is not needed to play MP3s, it makes more sense to use JavaSound classes.

Comment: I just want to play mp3 file. [here is the code that i viewed to play mp3 file](http://codeidol.com/java/swing/Audio/Add-MP3-Support-to-JMF/)

Comment: *"I just want to play mp3 file."*  I edited my answer to link to JavaSound code that can do that.  If you intend to use the `Player`/`MediaPlayer` of the JMF instead, you're on your own - since I cannot remember JMF very well, and could not be bothered looking back into it.

Comment: thank you for the link. But unfortunately even after including `mp3plugin.jar` i get the following exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface SourceDataLine supporting format MPEG1L3 44100.0 Hz, unknown bits per sample, stereo, unknown frame size, unknown frame rate,  is supported.
 at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getLine(AudioSystem.java:476)
 at mp3tester_mp3plugin.tester_1.main(tester_1.java:178)` when i entered something like `mymp3.mp3` Let me tell the path also `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext\mp3plugin.jar`

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson [I had to post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884974/why-do-i-get-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-line-matching-interface-sourc)

Answer (score 0):

appears that it's not distributed by default with the JDK (at least 1.6 JDK).   javax.sound.sampled is though I guess.  Also see the other answer, but note that apparently using javax.sound for mp3's isn't always compatible with all mp3's see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7040010/32453