# advice an easy ruby multiplatform audio library or jruby 's java libs utilization?

Tags: java, audio, jruby, wave

I'm simply tring play a wave/mp3 file from jruby.

Can you advice me what is the easiest library for ruby to do so in a multi-platform way ?

Since I'm using Jruby i think it would really make sense to use the java audio system, but I haven't found any tutorial on using that from Jruby.

So can you give me the quickest example of playing a wave file through java audio system ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just hacked one up: https://github.com/rdp/jruby-swing-helpers/blob/master/spec/play_mp3_audio.spec.rb

Comment: cool thanks, i have a few questions: 

1) does it play only mp3's (not wavs) ?
2) why you commented it like this: `require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/jl1.0.1.jar' # **third party jlayer mp3 jar <sigh>**` - are you mad because you had to use a third party lib instead of managing to use java's internal libs?

Anyway, thanks for giving me what i asked for!

Comment: yes mad. yes only mp3's (there's another file called play_audio.rb that works with waves).  So you were right on.

Comment: why was not possible to use java internal libs if i can ask? Thanks

Comment: basically the default jar's don't support it.  You could plugin to them but http://stackoverflow.com/a/9791696/32453 "it isn't always compatible" apparently